# Is there a way to "ping" the map to get the attention of other players?

Tags: diablo-iii

Many online co-op games feature an ability to beacon or ping the map, to indicate to other players that there is something of interest nearby that they should check out.

I'm kind of used to doing this in Dungeon Defenders, especially, where I often find bits of loot that would be better suited for the people I'm co-oping with.

Is there a way to call attention to a particular part of the map, or my current location?  How do I use this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to ping the mini-map, however you can use the <kbd>G</kbd> key to drop your banner on the ground to direct other player's attention to somewhere specific on the screen

Comment: I like dropping banners. Thing is, sometimes your allies are too far away to notice what you want them to do. D3 needs a ping function on the map, imo.

Comment: @RenoYeo I agree, dropping your banner is only useful if your allies can see what you're targeting on their screen, which limits its usefulness

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the emotes "Follow" or "Help". I'm not sure how far away the voice can be heard but I believe it always writes out the text of the emote. Not as useful as a map ping would be, but at least it's only a single key bind press like dropping the banner.